# Setting OptionValue in Knockoutjs cascading dropdown

Tags: knockout.js

Have a wierd issue where everything works fine until i specify optionsValue.  You could see my problem here

**works**
http://jsfiddle.net/abritez/ttyhE/2/

**doesn't work**
http://jsfiddle.net/abritez/ttyhE/4/

All you need to do is try running it with the select that that is commented, and you will see the issue when trying to cascade.

JSON data

```
var productCategories = [{
"name": "Comapany A",
"abbr": "cA",
"disiplineList": [{
    "name": "Math",
    "abbr": "math",
    "courseList": [{
        "name": "Algebra",
        "abbr": "alg"
    }]
}, {
    "name": "English",
    "abbr": "eng",
    "courseList": [{
        "name": "Phonics",
        "abbr": "phon"
    }]
}]
}, {
"name": "Company B",
"abbr": "cB",
"disiplineList": [{
    "name": "Gym",
    "abbr": "gym",
    "courseList": [{
        "name": "Kick Ball",
        "abbr": "kb"
    }]
}]
}];
```

HTML code

```
<table width='100%'>
<tbody data-bind='foreach: lines'>
  <tr>
         <td>

            <select data-bind='options: productCategories, optionsText: "name",  optionsCaption: "Select...", value: company'> </select>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td data-bind="with: company">
            <select data-bind='options: disiplineList, optionsText: "name", optionsCaption: "Select...", value: disipline'> </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
         <td data-bind="with: disipline">
            <select data-bind='options: courseList, optionsText: "name",  value: product'></select>
        </td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

​
Java Script (knockoutjs)

```
function ProductLine(){
                    self.company = ko.observable();
                    self.disipline = ko.observable();
                    self.product = ko.observable();

                    // Whenever the category changes, reset the product selection
                    self.company.subscribe(function() {
                        self.disipline(undefined);
                        self.product(undefined);
                    });
                }

                function Product(){
                    self.lines = ko.observableArray([new ProductLine()]); // Put one line in by default
                }

                ko.applyBindings(new Product());​
```

​

Comment: don't use *optionsValue* their use is awkward and not very valuable.. you don't need it. Show us what is your real problem. *optionsValue* is only for numbers, and when you build a *select* with an observableArray. like this: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/QKLpe/)

Comment: All i am trying to do is have the have the value be an abbreviation of the text. So for example, "United States of America" would have a value of "usa" and "New York City" would have a value of "nyc".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still i don't get it.

But if you want to show name and *abbr* u can:

```
 <select data-bind='options: productCategories,
       optionsText: function(item) {return item.name + " - " + item.abbr},  optionsCaption: "Select...", value: company'> </select>
```

if u want to display your *abbr* you can:

```
<td data-bind="with: company">
                            <select data-bind='options: disiplineList, optionsText: "name", optionsCaption: "Select...", value: disipline'> </select>
                             <span data-bind="text: abbr"/> <-- like this
                        </td>
```

Comment: Thanks I added a url of the version that doesn't work http://jsfiddle.net/abritez/ttyhE/4/ to make it clearer what i am trying to do.

Comment: you can't set string to optionsValue. What I am tryin to say is, you don't need it for any real application. *optionsText* and *optionsValue* brings the entire list for you *optionsText* for *Strings* and optionsValue for *Integers*. And *Value* set the selected object to a variable.